# How to enumerate disk volume names?

Tags: windows, winapi

How can i enumerate a list of all logical volumes on a disk? I want the name of the volume that is suitable for opening with `CreateFile`.

### What have you tried?

I've used the `FindFirstVolume`/`FindNextVolume` API to enumerate a list of volumes. It returns a list of names such as:

- `\\?\Volume{0b777018-3313-11e2-8ccd-806e6f6e6963}\`
- `\\?\Volume{0b777019-3313-11e2-8ccd-806e6f6e6963}\`
- `\\?\Volume{758a2cf2-cf3a-11e4-8dce-c86000d0b92a}\`
- `\\?\Volume{4f81d34b-34f4-11e2-9f6e-c86000d0b92a}\`

But none of those volume names are valid volume names. That is, none of those names can be passed to `CreateFile` to open the volume:

```
0x00000003 (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

The question ***might*** be how do i convert the thing returned by `FindFirstVolume` into a volume name?

But the real question is how do i enumerate volumes in the first place?

### Why not just use `\\.\C:`?

I wasn't asking how to hard-code a volume name; i was asking how to enumerate volume names.

Besides, not every volume has a drive letter, e.g.:

- `\\?\Volume{0b777019-3313-11e2-8ccd-806e6f6e6963}\` ==> `\\.\C:`
- `\\?\Volume{758a2cf2-cf3a-11e4-8dce-c86000d0b92a}\` ==> `\\.\D:`
- `\\?\Volume{0b777018-3313-11e2-8ccd-806e6f6e6963}\` ==> *the system reserved volume with no drive letter*
- `\\?\Volume{4f81d34b-34f4-11e2-9f6e-c86000d0b92a}\` ==> *a CD ROM that is mounted in a folder*

I swear there is an API to enumerate volumes.

## GetLogicalDriveStrings

The problem with [GetLogicalDriveStrings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364975%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) function is that it only returns logical *drives*:

- `C:\`
- `D:\`

and not **volumes**. In my case it misses two volumes:

- *System Reserved*
- *D:\CDROM*

that `FindFirstVolume` **does** correctly return.

## Converting Volume to drive number

1. Open the volume `\\?\Volume{0b777019-3313-11e2-8ccd-806e6f6e6963}` using **CreateFile**
2. Call **DeviceIoControl** with the `IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS` control code
3. This returns a series of `DISK_EXTENT` structures

```
   DISK_EXTENT = record
       DiskNumber: DWORD;
       StartingOffset: Int64;
       ExtentLength: Int64;
   end;
```

from which you can get the `DiskNumber`s.

```
function GetVolumeDiskExtents(VolumeName: string): TArray<DISK_EXTENT>;
var
    hVolume: THandle;
    vde:  PVolumeDiskExtents;
    bufferSize: Integer;
    bytesReturned: DWORD;
    le: DWORD;
begin
    SetLength(Result, 0);

    {
        CreateFile requires the trailing backslash of a volume name removed.
        While Volume API functions require the trailing backslash.
    }
//  VolumeName := ExcludeTrailingBackslash(VolumeName);

    bufferSize := SizeOf(vde)+2048*SizeOf(DISK_EXTENT);
    GetMem(vde, bufferSize);
    try
        hVolume := CreateFile(PChar(VolumeName),
                GENERIC_READ,
                FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                nil, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
        if (hVolume = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) then
            RaiseLastOSError;
        try
            if not (DeviceIoControl(hVolume, IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS,
                    nil, 0,
                    vde, bufferSize,
                    {var}bytesReturned, nil)) then
            begin
                le := GetLastError;
                if le = ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION then //ie. CD-ROM
                    Exit;

                raise Exception.CreateFmt('Could not get volume disk extents for volume "%s": %s (0x%s)', [VolumeName, SysErrorMessage(le), IntToHex(le, 8)]);
            end;
        finally
            CloseHandle(hVolume);
        end;

        SetLength(Result, vde^.NumberOfDiskExtents);
        Move(vde^.Extents[0], Result[0], SizeOf(DISK_EXTENT)*vde^.NumberOfDiskExtents);
    finally
        FreeMem(vde);
    end;
end;
```

### Bonus Reading

- [MSDN: Enumerating Volumes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364039%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [How to explicitly lock a mounted file system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29170575/how-to-explicitly-lock-a-mounted-file-system)

Comment: Do you know how to get the disk number it belongs to by the drive letter? Such like `C:` -> `PhysicalDrive0` or `Disk 0` (in my case Disk 0 is SSD), `D:` -> `PhysicalDrive1` or `Disk 1` (in my case Disk 1 is HDD).

Comment: @JoeHuang Be away that one physical disk (e.g. `PhysicalDisk0` can contain multiple volumes (e.g `C:`, `D:`). And also one volume (e.g. `C:`) can be on multiple physical disks (e.g. `PhysicalDisk0`, `PhysicalDisk1`)  because, for example, because of using RAID.

Comment: Thanks your reply, but I found the solution. Open the volume by `CreateFile` then call `DeviceIoControl` the handle with `IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS`.

Comment: @JoeHuang That was what i added to my question as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer to your question is hidden inside [Naming a Volume](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365248.aspx). When using a *volume GUID path*, the rules are slightly different:

> All volume and mounted folder functions that take a volume GUID path as an input parameter require the trailing backslash. [...] but this is not the case with the [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx) function. **You can open a volume by calling CreateFile and omit the trailing backslash from the volume name you specify.** CreateFile processes a volume GUID path with an appended backslash as the root directory of the volume.

The solution is easy: Strip the trailing backslash from a volume GUID path to open the volume using `CreateFile`.

In other words, while volume management functions such as:

- GetVolumeInformation
- GetVolumePathNamesForVolumeName

*do* take the full volume name returned by `FindFirstVolume`/`FindNextVolume`, CreateFile requires the returned trailing backslash removed:

- `\\?\Volume{0b777018-3313-11e2-8ccd-806e6f6e6963}`
- `\\?\Volume{0b777019-3313-11e2-8ccd-806e6f6e6963}`
- `\\?\Volume{758a2cf2-cf3a-11e4-8dce-c86000d0b92a}`
- `\\?\Volume{4f81d34b-34f4-11e2-9f6e-c86000d0b92a}`

Comment: `CreateFile` will actually succeed in opening the root directory if `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` is requested. Otherwise `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` isn't exactly helpful, but the NT status code from `ntdll!RtlGetLastNtStatus` reveals the real error is `STATUS_FILE_IS_A_DIRECTORY`, i.e. the call tried to open a directory as a regular file.

Comment: Interestingly, Windows only translates NT's `STATUS_FILE_IS_A_DIRECTORY` to `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` when `lpFileName` ends with a backslash. Otherwise trying to open a directory without a trailing backslash results in `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

Comment: @eryksun: Interesting information. It all makes sense now (except for the less-than-informative error code). The documentation for [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx) does point out that the `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` flag is required to obtain a handle to a directory, but it didn't connect to the `ERROR_PATH_NO_FOUND` error code, until you spelled it out.

Comment: @IInspectable: while `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` is required for directory handles, the backup privilege isn't. There seems to be some confusion about this, since I have seen several developers attempting to enable the backup privilege prior to working with `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS`.