# How to prevent windows from accessing and detecting new volumes while writing a raw image file to PhysicalDrive?

Tags: winapi, windows-10, dd, disk-partitioning, usb-flash-drive

After lots and lots of try and error I am now able to flash/write a raw image file (containing multiple partitions) to `\\.\PhysicalDriveN` (SD-Card in my case) by just using Windows Api calls (*see below*).

But as soon as I have some explorer windows open and click around, the write process fails (*error 433*). Another annoying problem are popup messages telling me that a new volume has to be formatted (at the beginning, while I am still writing!) or autoplay asks me to select an action (after I'm finished).

How to do it right?

Here is what I'm doing now (any improvements welcome!):

- for each command, a new Handle is opened and closed, using [CreateFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/FileAPI/nf-fileapi-createfilea)("\\.\PhysicalDrive1", ...) (also tried doing everything with the same Handle, and experimented with various flags like FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, dwShareMode=0, ...)
- [DeviceIoControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ioapiset/nf-ioapiset-deviceiocontrol)(Handle, [IOCTL_DISK_DELETE_DRIVE_LAYOUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/WinIoCtl/ni-winioctl-ioctl_disk_delete_drive_layout), ...)
- *Sleep 5s*
- while(...) [WriteFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-writefile)(Handle, ...)
- DeviceIoControl(Handle, [IOCTL_DISK_UPDATE_PROPERTIES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/WinIoCtl/ni-winioctl-ioctl_disk_update_properties), ...)
- DeviceIoControl(Handle, [IOCTL_DISK_ARE_VOLUMES_READY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/ioctl-disk-are-volumes-ready), ...)

If I don't touch anything (and ignore the popups), this works most of the time.

**How can I get exclusive access and prevent windows from disturbing me?**

Additional question: how can I know how long to wait after deleting the drive layout? If I start too early, writing fails after some seconds (but some data has already been written).

This should all run unattended. At the end I need the just flashed partition to be available, so I can add some files. Even though I'm running "are volumes ready", this doesn't always work immediately and I need multiple retries. Todo: after the files are added, the disk should be [ejected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918248/how-to-eject-a-usb-removable-disk-volume-similar-to-the-eject-function-in-win).

I tried *diskpart / [automount disable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/automount)*, but this seems not to change anything.

I tried *diskpart / [offline disk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/offline-disk)*, but it says this isn't supported for removable media.

I tried various command line tools, like [dd.exe](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dd-invocation.html#dd-invocation) from the GNU core utils, but they all have the same or even more problems.

**EDIT**
@DrakeWu-MSFT pointed me to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29170575/how-to-explicitly-lock-a-mounted-file-system) - yes, enumerating the volumes and dismounting them is something I could try, but I would call it a workaround, since the first thing I already do is deleting all volumes. Is that the wrong way? I would prefer to prevent Windows 10 from automatically creating new volumes after I deleted them, so I can just work on physical disks and not logical volumes.

I analyzed the open source [Win32 Disk Imager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) - it doesn't have the problem I have: while it is writing the image, other processes get *access denied* as it should be. It achieves this by locking and dismounting the volume, which is exactly the accepted solution from above:

- DeviceIoControl(Handle, [FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ni-winioctl-fsctl_lock_volume), ...)
- DeviceIoControl(Handle, [FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ni-winioctl-fsctl_dismount_volume), ...)

However, what if there is no volume? Then that tool doesn't work at all, it requires a drive letter (and I guess it would fail if there are multiple volumes and drive letters assigned to that disk).

So, if only volumes can be locked, but not disks, I had to create a dummy volume first, just to be able to get a lock? I don't like that! Still hoping for a better solution...

Comment: Is this answer your question?[How to explicitly lock a mounted file system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29170575/how-to-explicitly-lock-a-mounted-file-system)

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT, thanks for the interesting link. I replied by editing above.

Comment: Have you tried to set the disk offline: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ni-winioctl-ioctl_disk_set_disk_attributes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ns-winioctl-set_disk_attributes also disable Explorer autoruns https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/967715/how-to-disable-the-autorun-functionality-in-windows

Comment: @SimonMourier, took a while, but now I tried it (using `diskpart / offline disk` command) and got the error "The operation is not supported on removable media." - so this cannot be used here :(